# bash complete: list directory names from a defined directory?

Tags: bash, tab-completion, mailman

I need the directory names in /mailman/lists to tab-complete as an argument (without any slashes) to the 'list_members' command regardless of where I am in the filesystem.

In tcsh (on our old server), I wrote one line to do what I needed:

```
complete list_members 'p,*,F:/mailman/lists,,' #tcsh
```

bash's implementation seems to be more complex. How can I implement this same behavior using bash?

The tab-completion needs to be context-sensitive so that whatever part of the argument I've already typed narrows down the search, just like standard bash completion. Example:

```
list_members sys<TAB> #only shows names beginning with sys
```

I've tried a few solutions after looking at examples, but they don't work properly.

One failing example:

```
function _listlists()
{
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -C 'ls /mailman/lists' ) )
}

complete -F _listlists list_members
```

Which yields the error:

```
-bash: compgen: warning: -C option may not work as you expect
```

Another failing example:

```
function _listlists()
{
    cd /mailman/lists
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -d ) )
    cd -
}

complete -F _listlists list_members
```

This shows all results from that dir piped to 'more', but it doesn't respond to the partial argument I've already typed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My colleague came up with this solution right after I posted the question. It works well:

```
function _listlists()
{
    local cur
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$(ls -d /mailman/lists/*/|cut -d "/" -f 4)" -- $cur ) )
}

complete -F _listlists list_members
```

Comment: How can I support files names containing spaces?

Answer (score 3):

I tested a solution with the HOME-folders (no mailman on my host). Is this what you are looking for?

```
function _homes() {
    local homes=("/home/$2"*)
    [[ -e ${homes[0]} ]] && COMPREPLY=( "${homes[@]##*/}" )
}
complete -F _homes homes
alias homes='echo you selected:'
```

Comment: Thank you, return42. I'm sorry that I didn't get to test your solution.

Comment: This solution worked better for me when what I was completing was effectively equivalent to `ls`.

Comment: One can refer [this link](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) to understand what ${homes[@]##*/} in the solution means